# Is there any way to get inputs values in array by class in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

as the title say is there any way to get inputs values in array by class in Javascript? I'am trying to get each input value using class name and store them in array like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Scal").click(function() {
        var map = [];
        $('input').each(function() {
            map[$(this).attr('class="Sc"')] = $(this).val();
        });

        alert(map.Sc1);
    
    });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CCE GPA Calculator</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=.80; maximum-scale=.80; minimum-scale=.80;" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/HideSpiner.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.flatui.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-rc.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tbenggpacalc.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="f"> <a data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="pop" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-icon="home" title="Home" href="index.html">Home</a>

         <h1>BENG & BSc</h1>

    </div>
    <form id="form">
    <div id="GPA1" class="GPA1">
        <div class="BENG" id="N1">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li style="border:none">
                 <h1>Module 1:</h1>

            </li>
            <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
                <label for="Sc1">Credits:</label>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" name="Sc1" id="Sc1" class="Sc" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
            </li>
            <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
                <label for="Sgrade1" class="select">Grade:</label>
                <select class="Sgrade" data-theme="f" id="Sgrade1">
                    <option value="-1">—</option>
                    <option value="4">A</option>
                    <option value="3.7">A-</option>
                    <option value="3.3">B+</option>
                    <option value="3">B</option>
                    <option value="2.7">B-</option>
                    <option value="2.3">C+</option>
                    <option value="2">C</option>
                    <option value="1.7">C-</option>
                    <option value="1.3">D+</option>
                    <option value="1">D</option>
                    <option value="0">F</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        <div class="BENG" id="N2">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li style="border:none">
                 <h1>Module 2:</h1>

            </li>
            <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
                <label for="Sc2">Credits:</label>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" name="Sc2" id="Sc2" class="Sc" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
            </li>
            <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
                <label for="Sgrade2" class="select">Grade:</label>
                <select class="Sgrade" data-theme="f" id="Sgrade2">
                    <option value="-1">—</option>
                    <option value="4">A</option>
                    <option value="3.7">A-</option>
                    <option value="3.3">B+</option>
                    <option value="3">B</option>
                    <option value="2.7">B-</option>
                    <option value="2.3">C+</option>
                    <option value="2">C</option>
                    <option value="1.7">C-</option>
                    <option value="1.3">D+</option>
                    <option value="1">D</option>
                    <option value="0">F</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        <div class="BENG" id="N3">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li style="border:none">
                 <h1>Module 3:</h1>

            </li>
            <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
                <label for="Sc3">Credits:</label>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" name="Sc3" id="Sc3" class="Sc" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
            </li>
            <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
                <label for="Sgrade3" class="select">Grade:</label>
                <select class="Sgrade" data-theme="f" id="Sgrade3">
                    <option value="-1">—</option>
                    <option value="4">A</option>
                    <option value="3.7">A-</option>
                    <option value="3.3">B+</option>
                    <option value="3">B</option>
                    <option value="2.7">B-</option>
                    <option value="2.3">C+</option>
                    <option value="2">C</option>
                    <option value="1.7">C-</option>
                    <option value="1.3">D+</option>
                    <option value="1">D</option>
                    <option value="0">F</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        <div class="BENG" id="N4">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li style="border:none">
                 <h1>Module 4:</h1>

            </li>
            <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
                <label for="Sc4">Credits:</label>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" name="Sc4" id="Sc4" class="Sc" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
            </li>
            <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
                <label for="Sgrade4" class="select">Grade:</label>
                <select class="Sgrade" data-theme="f" id="Sgrade4">
                    <option value="-1">—</option>
                    <option value="4">A</option>
                    <option value="3.7">A-</option>
                    <option value="3.3">B+</option>
                    <option value="3">B</option>
                    <option value="2.7">B-</option>
                    <option value="2.3">C+</option>
                    <option value="2">C</option>
                    <option value="1.7">C-</option>
                    <option value="1.3">D+</option>
                    <option value="1">D</option>
                    <option value="0">F</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        <div class="BENG" id="N5">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li style="border:none">
                 <h1>Module 5:</h1>

            </li>
            <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
                <label for="Sc5">Credits:</label>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" name="Sc5" id="Sc5" class="Sc" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
            </li>
            <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
                <label for="Sgrade5" class="select">Grade:</label>
                <select class="Sgrade" data-theme="f" id="Sgrade5">
                    <option value="-1">—</option>
                    <option value="4">A</option>
                    <option value="3.7">A-</option>
                    <option value="3.3">B+</option>
                    <option value="3">B</option>
                    <option value="2.7">B-</option>
                    <option value="2.3">C+</option>
                    <option value="2">C</option>
                    <option value="1.7">C-</option>
                    <option value="1.3">D+</option>
                    <option value="1">D</option>
                    <option value="0">F</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            
            </div>

        
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="buttons">
            <li class="ui-body ui-body-b" style="border:none">
                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                    <div>
                        <button type="button" id="Sadd" name="Sadd" data-theme="f">Add Module</button>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-body ui-body-b" style="border:none">
                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                    <div>
                        <button type="button" id="Sremove" name="Sremove" data-theme="f">Remove Module</button>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <li data-role="fieldcontain" style="border:none">
                    <label for="Sres">Your GPA:</label>
                    <input type="number" step="0.01" name="Sres" id="Sres" value="" data-clear-btn="true" readonly>
                </li>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-body ui-body-b" style="border:none">
                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                    <div>
                        <button type="button" id="Scal" name="Scal" data-theme="f">Calculate</button>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-body ui-body-b" style="border:none">
                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                    <div>
                        <button type="reset" data-theme="d">Reset</button>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

By the way the type of input is number

Update:- I've added my html code. what I want is to get each input box of credits and store it in an array using class

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: should it duplicates if several class presented?

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Based on the HTML you provide, what exactly would you expect the result to look like?

Comment: @BasSlagter Numbers that user will insert in the input box. I am still learning actually and I want to sum up all the input values that will user will insert but first I want to see the alert of one of the input to test that calling the class is working fine

Comment: @AnthonyGrist as I said above

Comment: You might want to use .push() on the map array instead.

Comment: Look at last snippet in my answer. I think it what are you looking for.

Comment: @vp_arth yeah I saw it. I will give it try when am done modifying my html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This create <className, arrayOfInputs> map:

```
var map = {};
$('input').each(function() {
   var $this = this;
   ($this.className||'').split(/\s+/).forEach(function(className){
      if(!map[className]) map[className] = [];
      map[className].push($this);
   })
});
```

---

This collects `select` values

```
var map = {};
$('input[class="Sc"]').closest('ul').find('select').each(function(){
  map[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});
```

---

This collects `input` values, using input `name` as a key

```
var map = {};
$('input[class="Sc"]').each(function(){
  map[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a map of classnames to values? If so, it's just a small error in the `$(this).attr('class="Sc"')` bit.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Scal").click(function() {
        var map = [];
        $('input').each(function() {
            map[$(this).attr('class')] = $(this).val();
        });
        alert(map.Sc1);
    });
});
```

Note that if classnames are not unique, values will be overwritten. Why not use $(this).attr('name') instead, which is a better representation of form data when submitted?

Comment: Ok I will do it with name instead of class by the way I tried what $(this).attr('class') before but it didn't work any way I will follow your advice by using the name instead of class

Comment: Array is object too, but using it instead of `{}` causes pain while debug.

Comment: @vp_arth I see, Thanks for the advice

Comment: Good point @vp_arth, so it should be `var map = {};`. Though confusingly, you'd still need to use the square brackets to assign values...